# Leveling-smoothing an exterior cement patio

Tags: patio

I paid for a 16' x 16' cement slab to be laid down so I can build a shade spot for BBQ and enjoying the evenings. My problem is that I did not want a rough surface. I want to be able to walk out in bare feet to have morning coffee.

I told the guy that. Guess what? Yep, it has small rocks on the surface. What is the least expensive way to level this my self?

Comment: "Small rocks"? Is it an exposed aggregate patio? A photo would be invaluable. What does your contract stipulate? Concrete is normally finished with either a smooth (troweled) or textured (broomed) surface. This sounds like neither.

Comment: cheaper and more practical to get a pair of $5 flip-flops.

Answer (score 1):

The only good ways to get a truly smooth surface at this point is to 1) cover the slab with tile, or 2) grind it smooth.

You can install porcelain or quarry tile for a truly finished surface. Obviously there's some expense and effort involved with this option.

On several occasions I've seen businesses bring in companies to grind their concrete to a polish finish. It's visually attractive and very smooth.